# Unable to get property empty of undefined or null reference

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, office-365, sharepoint-on-prem

I encountered a strange error while trying to save (MS Office) documents to a SharePoint 2010 sub site.

[image: Sharepoint error]

It happens with all file formats and in every library on that specific sub site. Resetting the settings of Internet Explorer and installing a new version of Office (365) didn't solve the issue. How to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1.2.Open below mentioned files from all your SP Web front end servers in a text editor such as notepad

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\DocumentLibrary\DocLib\FileDlg.htm 

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\filedlg.htm
```

and modify the below line:

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"
```

to

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5"
```

If not present at all please add in head section

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5"
```

3. Save the file back to the original location overwriting the original
4. Perform an IIS Reset.

That's All. This solves the issue.